Symfony cache don't work with relations entity
I've used the cache component with Symfony and encountered a problem. When I retrieve my data from the cache, the entities with relationships are not set. Does anyone know how to solve this?
$cache = new FilesystemAdapter();
$categories = $cache->get('indexCategories', function (ItemInterface $item) use ($entityManager): Array {
    $item->expiresAfter(30);
    $categories = $entityManager->getRepository(Category::class)->findAll();
    
    return $categories;
});

The first image shows what I aim for - obtaining the entity in the relationship.
Desired Outcome
The second image shows my current situation, where none of my relationship entities are present.
Current Situation
I'm trying to access the entity in a OneToMany relationship between Category and SubCategory.

Symfony Cache use php serialization.
But, serialization of doctrine collection is not available.
See here : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/stable/serialization.html
One way might be to add the Serializable interface to your Category entity, and implement your own serialization and de-serialiszation method.
